# Elementary mechanics question about centripetal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

The situation is as follows: a coil (the cube $S$), which is free to move along a rod $l$ (which makes a uniform circular motion). There is also a frictional force $F_f$ acting. I want to know the maximum constant speed of the coil at which it does not slide upward. Say I define a positive coordinate system as in the figure below (forces to "right" and "up" as positive).

Perhaps I am solving it a bit tediously, given a triangle with ratio is given, but if I solve the force balances for the $x$ and $y$ directions I get:

$
F_N = \frac{m g}{\cos(\theta) - \mu_s \sin(\theta)}
$

$
-F_N = \frac{m v^2}{\rho (\mu_s \cos(\theta) + sin(\theta)}
$

If I solve for $v^2$, and substitute the known $F_N$ into this equation it results in the following equation:

$
v^2 = - \frac{g \rho (\mu_s \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))}{-\mu_s \sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta)}
$

If I then fill in the equation with the known values I get:

$
v^2 = - ...
$

Which gives a complex solution for the velocity? If I then define the defined axis system as: up and left positive I do get a real answer, and this is the correct answer. Why/how does this happen? Does the direction of the centripetal force have anything to do with it?

[image]

Comment: On the one hand, you are asking for the maximum speed so the coil doesn't slide up. On the other hand you are saying there is friction caused by sliding up the rod., which would mean kinetic friction. This doesn't make sense to me. Static friction is needed to keep the rod from sliding up.

Comment: @BobD It indeed didn't make sense, apologies.